# Azure Devops - Approve own PR when I am required reviewer

Tags: azure, devops, policy

I am using Azure for development. I want to be informed on every PR and approve it myself, since all others are very new to the project. So I set myself as required reviewer. I don't want developers to approve their own PRs. So I think this is where the trouble starts.

I cannot complete my own PRs as it still shows "Approval from required reviewer missing" - altough I clicked "Approve" and am listed in the approvals. Is this because I forbid requesters to approve their PRs themselves?

Did anyone else have this problem?

Cheers,
Georg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself :D

When adding a required reviewer, you must tick "Allow requesters to approve their own requests". This allows only the required reviewer to do so.

Cheers : )

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I tried checking the "Allow requestors to approve their own changes" checkbox in both the branch policy and the automatically included reviewers policy, but I still can't complete my own PR.  It errors saying "0 of 1 reviewers approved", and "At least 1 reviewer besides author must approve". Any other hints you can provide please?